# IOS 9, IPhone 6S plus, metal, unable to link to function frexp

Tags: ios, iphone, metal

New to IOS metal and I am trying to write a kernel. My function needs to link to the frexp function. Unfortunately, my kernel referencing the frexp function will not compile.

```
    float exponent = 0.0;
    float mantissa = frexp(value, exponent);
```

The Metal documentation lists the function protocol as:
  T frexp(T x, Ti &exp)

I am able to compile to other similar math functions such as exp, exp2, exp10, ldexp.

Has anyone been able to link to Metal's frexp function? Or know how I can view the metal_math include file to see the frexp protocol the compiler is referencing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After reading my own question I found my mistake, the corrected code looks as follows.

```
int exponent = 0.0;
float mantissa = frexp(value, exponent);
```